Is there any way to view historical data on market capitalization?
Is there any way to view historical data on market capitalization?
I would like to calculate a market capitalization weighted index with only the top 10 nasdaq stocks (like nasdaq 10).
I have tried using yfinance to calculate the historical number of shares outstanding based on stock split information and multiplying it by the adjusted share price to calculate market capitalization. However, the data was not credible as there was missing data or the numbers seemed to be wrong.
